# error: cannot find symbol method setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

I am using Android Studio on macbook for creating simple camera app following official android documentation. However, when I try to call `camera.setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder)` I am getting following error:

> Error:(29, 16) error: cannot find symbol method
>   setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder)

Also my CameraPreview class is as follows:

```
package com.opencv.camerapreview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;


public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera=camera;
        this.surfaceHolder= getHolder();
        this.surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
}
```

It looks like this is some linking issue in Android Studio. Can anybody shed some light on why this could happen and solution. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have imported

```
import android.graphics.Camera;
```

and you should import

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
```

or even

```
import android.hardware.camera2;
```

if you are targeting API 21 and above.